# How to find the email Ids of the required attendees in a outlook appointment item?

Tags: c#, asp.net, outlook-addin

Here is my code :

```
Meeting Meeting = new Meeting();
Outlook.AppointmentItem oulookMeeting;
Meeting.Email_Address = (oulookMeeting.RequiredAttendees == string.Empty ?   string.Empty : oulookMeeting.RequiredAttendees);
```

In this i only get the names of the RequiredAttendees. Is it possible to get their repective email Ids somehow ?
please help.

Comment: Do you develop an Outlook add-in?

Comment: Yes I have built an Outlook AddIn

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Loop through the AppointmentItem.Recipients collection and look for the recipients with the Recipient.Type property  == OlMailRecipientType.olTo